# How to dynamically add new input fields to my page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to append a new input field on the click of a button.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('row');      
  document.getElementById('create_row').onclick = function (e) {
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<input type="text" name="ain[]" placeholder="something..."/>';
}
```

```html
<div id="row"></div>
<button type="button" id="create_row">button</button>
```

This appears to be is working great! But every time I press the button, the added field contents is disappearing.

So, I want to leave the added field's contents in place.

Help! ㅠ_ㅠ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The innerHTML of an element does not change just because you type something into an input field.

Therefore, when you do `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "something new"` then the contents of the DIV will be as it initially was, plus that `"something new"`. Now the innerHTML has changed, but you lose all typed text because your input fields will be thrown away and replaced.

That means you should avoid overwriting the innerHTML.

Create a new DOM node instead ([read about the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)) and append it to the DIV.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('row');      
var row = document.getElementById('create_row');

row.onclick = function (e) {
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "text";
    newInput.name = "ain[]";
    newInput.placeholder = "type something...";

    div.appendChild(newInput);
    newInput.focus();
}
```

```css
#row {
  width: 100px;
}
#row > input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="row"></div>
<button id="create_row">Create Row</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for kindly answer!

What if I have more than two "div"?````

like.... `<div class="a"><div class="b"><input ..... /></div></div>`

Comment: Create more elements, append them to each other in the right order. At some point begins to become easier to look into a tool that does that for you (keyword HTML templating), but I encourage you to try without the help of a tool first. This will give you some insight into how the DOM works and how much work these tools do under the hood.

Comment: Okay! I try to find my way with yours hint! Thank you. :D